# Remove all underscores until last number

Tags: regex, kotlin

I faced with the following problem. I need to remove all underscores between the start of the string and last digit in string (like was: 123_456__ - became: 123456__). I used the usual loop for it, which goes through string.length - 1 down to 0 and when the symbol is digit I start the new loop from the 0 to the i, where i is position of the found digit and forming new string skipping underscores. But it seems that there are some ways to replace it with regex or more "Kotlin-style" code, but I do not know how to do it. Is it possible to do it in more convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to to this is to use string functions like `takeLastWhile` / `drop` etc.

```kotlin
val s = "123_456__"
val end = s.takeLastWhile { !it.isDigit() }
val start = s.dropLast(end.length).filter { it != '_' } // or replace("_", "")
val result = start + end
println(result)
```